# JSON to SOAP WSO2 Api manager xml sequence

Tags: json, xml, soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I would to publish a SOAP service as REST(json) API . The service operation I want to expose has a xml sequence element in the WSDL/XSD definition:

```
<xs:complexType name="hellolist">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="hellolistResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I don't know how to map a JSON array to a xml sequence using PayloadFactory. All the samples I found deal only with simple json and SOAP messages like this [sample WSO2 transformation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Convert+a+JSON+Message+to+SOAP+and+SOAP+to+JSON).
I would like to transform this json message:

```
{"hellolist":{"name":["Peter","Mary","Ann","James"]}}
```

To this soap message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:dum="http://dummyservice2.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
         <dum:hellolist>
           <name>Peter</name>
           <name>Mary</name>
           <name>Ann</name>
           <name>James</name>
         </dum:hellolist>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you stucked with mapping a JSON array into SOAP? Is that all?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the length of the JSON array is different in each request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use payload factory mediator to do this. It can be used to transform or replace message content in between the client and the back-end server. In the case of your scenario you can configure a proxy service as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="json_to_xml_factory"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <dum:hellolist xmlns:dum="http://dummyservice2.com/">
                  <name xmlns="">$1</name>
                  <name xmlns="">$2</name>
                  <name xmlns="">$3</name>
                  <name xmlns="">$4</name>
               </dum:hellolist>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.hellolist.name[0]"/>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.hellolist.name[1]"/>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.hellolist.name[2]"/>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.hellolist.name[3]"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Please refer below links for more information on this.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/PayloadFactory+Mediator
http://christinetechtips.blogspot.com/2014/02/payload-factory-mediators-to-work-with.html
http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2013/05/wso2-esb-payload-mediator-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you, but your approach does not solve the problem. The length of the list is variable, in a request the length can have 4 elements and the next request 8.
`<xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a non-static payload (your case), payload-factory-mediator will not be the solution (only for static payload). The best way for your kind of a problem is using xslt mediator + enrich mediator in WSO2 ESB. You can try out this example, https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+440%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+XSLT

Or you can use script mediator in case, as explained in this example.https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+350%3A+Introduction+to+the+Script+Mediator+Using+JavaScript . Yet not the most preffered way.

I have done your kind of conversions using WSO2 ESB as I described above. But I don't know whether those mediator tools are also available with WSO2 APIM (I couldn't find any example when I googled for your problem).

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps mention below

Steps to Convert a SOAP Test service in SoapUI with assertions into JSON service with assertions

1. Copy the project xml file of SOAP UI project
2. Open the copied xml file
3. Find the format for all assertion types in JSON that is equal in SOAP call assertion
4. Now convert all the soap assertions in the config node of the test step node to JSON assertion config node format as found in the previous step
5. Convert the SOAP call request into JSON call by changing all the fields as below
   • Add the output_format node
   • Add the Rest call – service name
   • Remove the nodes without value and convert the others into JSON format like {“node name” : “value”} etc.,
6. In the test step node type attribute – it will be “request” change it to “httprequest”
7. Save the file and open it in SOAP UI

Now you can see all the services in the newly opened project will be in JSON format and all assertions will be available that were in SOAP call previously.

also refer the [link](https://prassannasautomation.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/soap-call-to-json-call-with-assertions/) which helps to convert the request completely including the assertions

please reply if it is not helpful

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! But please note that [overt self-promotion is not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: Thanks for the comment !

Comment: Sorry, but this question is about WSO2 Api Management tool.